# Show that $p(t_0\ \text{is a local maximum for}\ B)=0$.

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion

Let $B$ a Brownian motion. Show that for all $t_0$,$$p\{t_0\text{ is a local maximum for }B\}=0$$
but a.s. local maximal are a countable dense set in $(0,\infty )$.

For the first part, 
$$p\{t_0\text{ is a local maximum for }B\}=p\{\exists \delta>0\mid \forall t: |t-t_0|<\delta, B_t\leq B_{t_0}\}$$

So I define $\{S_t=B_t-B_{t_0}\}_{t>0}$ which is also a Brownian. Then, I have to show that $$p\{\exists \delta>0\mid \forall t, |t|<\delta, S_t\leq 0 \}$$
but it doesn't really help. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For fixed $t_0 \geq 0$, we have

$$\{\omega; t_0 \, \text{is not a local maximum for $t \mapsto B_t(\omega)$}\} \supseteq \{\omega; \forall \delta>0 \exists t \in [t_0,t_0+\delta]: B_{t}(\omega)>B_{t_0}(\omega)\}.$$

If we set $W_s := B_{s+t_0}-B_{t_0}$, $s \geq 0$, then we can rewrite this as

$$\begin{align*} \{\omega; t_0 \, \text{is not a local maximum for $t \mapsto B_t(\omega)$}\} &\supseteq \{\omega; \forall \delta >0 \exists s \in [0,\delta]: W_s(\omega)>0\} \\ &= \bigcap_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \{\omega; \exists s \in [0,1/k]: W_s(\omega)>0\}. \end{align*}$$

The assertion follows if we can show that

$$\mathbb{P}(\exists s \in [0,1/k]: W_s>0) =1 \tag{1}$$

for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. It is well-known that

$$M_t := \sup_{s \in [0,t]} W_s \sim |W_t|$$

for any Brownian motion $(W_t)_{t \geq 0}$ (this is e.g. a consequence of the reflection principle). Therefore,

$$\mathbb{P}(\exists s \in [0,1/k]: W_s>0)= \mathbb{P}(M_{1/k}>0) = \mathbb{P}(|B_{1/k}|>0) = 1,$$

and this proves $(1)$.